# Python Kivy How to chnage the SlideTransition colour

Tags: python, animation, kivy, transition

How would I change the colour of a slide transition?
In my kv file

```
<screen1>
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.35, "y": 0.5}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            text: "Return"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

When the transition goes to the right, the background colour of the transition is black. How would I change this?

Comment: Perhaps this is the root (parent) widget's color..

Comment: so how would I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve by setting the `window.clearcolor`
for example:
`Window.clearcolor = (.1, .8, .9, 9)`